# Error : Could not determine java version from '11.0.19'

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, gradle-wrapper

I was using java 8 until now, but I needed to upgrade java to jdk-11 for one project. As I installed newer version and set JAVA_HOME & PATH to new jdk-11 path, I started getting this error in eclipse :

> An internal error occurred during: "Update Installed JREs".
> Could not determine java version from '11.0.19'.

In eclipse properties -> JAVA_PATH and JRE I changed the Libraries to jdk-11 but nothing worked.
I created new workspace and also restarted my pc.
Gradle version I am using - 6.8.3

Note : From Command Prompt with "gradle clean build -x test" I am able to build the project successfully
And I tried the solutions which are already given on other similar questions but from what I think is my gradle wrapper is not the problem and those solution didn't solved my problem

Comment: I also encountered this issue. I think it is because Eclipse tries to parse the java version which is now in a different format.
For me, installing the latest version of eclipse fixed the issue (note that you can still use your projects from the older eclipse Version)

Comment: Oh okay, I will try running project with new eclipse version